# How do I access a field inside a document inside a collection in Firebase (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-studio

I have a collection called "users" and a document withing users, which contains some informations, such as Email, Name and Phone

[image]

However when I try to access the name using:

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
String Name = currentFirebaseUser.getDisplayName;
```

it returns an empty string. It works with e-mail but not with name.

Is there an alternative way to get the name that don't envolve the "getDisplay" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentFirebaseUser.getDisplayName()` returns the Username associated with that account which has nothing to do with your Firestore Database.

To get the data from the firestore database, first create a POJO class for eg. `User`

```
public class User {
    private String email, fName, phone;
    public User(){
        //Required for firestore
    }

    public User(String email, String fName, String phone) {
        this.email = email;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you must be using the firebase user's UID as the document name.
To get the user details from firestore:

```
FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("users").document(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
        String fName = user.getfName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        String phone = user.getPhone();
    }
});
```